# PyUserInput - stopping PyMouseEvent

Tags: python

I am trying to build a program whose first part is saving user clicks for calibration purposes.

I am using PyUserInput for this (on Python 3.4.3) and following their tutorial on GitHub. Currently, this is my code:

```
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent

positions = []

class Click(PyMouseEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        PyMouseEvent.__init__(self)

    def click(self, x, y, button, press):
        if button == 1:
            if press:
                print('Click! X=%d - Y=%d' % (x, y))
                positions.append((x, y))
                print(positions)
        if len(positions) >= 4:
            self.stop()

C = Click()
C.run()

print('Calibrated')
```

The problem I'm running into is that, even after the PyMouseEvent stops (when position reaches 4 values), I cannot run anything after it (i.e. 'Calibrated' does not print).

**How can I continue to run scripts after calling stop() on PyMouseEvent?**

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a "legal" solution. The idea is to replace `stop()` method calls with raising exception and wrapping `run()` method call inside `try: except:` statements. I recommend making your own exception by subclassing `Exception` for better understanding of the code.

Here:

```
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent

positions = []

class ListenInterrupt(Exception):
    pass

class Click(PyMouseEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        PyMouseEvent.__init__(self)
        return

    def click(self, x, y, button, press):
        if button == 1:
            if press:
                print('Click! X=%d - Y=%d' % (x, y))
                positions.append((x, y))
                print(positions)
        if len(positions) >= 4:
            raise ListenInterrupt("Calibrated.")
        return

C = Click()
try:
    C.run()
except ListenInterrupt as e:
    print(e.args[0])
```

This should stop event listener. If you wish to recalibrate using this approach, simply reruning same instance of listener won't work. The solution is deleting current instance of `class Click` and instantiating new one each time.

```
del C
C = Click()
```